# Restriction of sending events based on time In Stream Analytics Azure

Tags: azure, streaming, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

In my Azure Stream Analytics Job, Want to restrict events sending to service bus queue after certain time of the day.

SA Query :

```
Select
    *
INTO
    servicebusqueue
FROM
    eventhub
Where name  = 'abc'
*AND Time < 1 PM*
```

How to write query for the "time < 1PM" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/datepart-azure-stream-analytics) should work (haven't tested this right now)

Assuming `Time` is a field from your input data.

```
Select
    *
INTO
    servicebusqueue
FROM
    eventhub
Where name  = 'abc'
AND DATEPART(hour, Time) < 13
```